# assigning NULL to a struct pointer gives error and meaning of segmentation fault

Tags: pointers, null, segmentation-fault, initialization

I have this simple code of c,c++, which runs fine:

```
struct node{
       int x;
       struct node* next;
       };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a,b,c;
  struct node *root, *node1, *node2, *leaf;


    root = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );  
    //root = NULL;
    root->next = 0;   
    root->x = 12;


  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

1. Now if I assign root = NULL or 0, instead of malloc, it gives me this error-
   "An access violation (Segmentation fault) raised in your program"
   While in the next line i could assign 0 to next pointer. Please explain
2. In this forum I read segmentation fault occurs when we try to access secured memory space, while operating system defines it like a page fault when the required data is not found in memory. Are they related ? (SF of C, C++ and SF of Operating System)

Answer (score 1):

If you set  `root = NULL;`, it will do exactly that, and will not generate a segmentation fault.

The segfault happens on the next line, when you try to dereference the NULL pointer.

If you comment out the two lines below it, you will observe no segfault.

Comment: It should be an accepted answer!
it works 101% for me. Thanks @merlin2011

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and should not dereference A NULL pointer.